# ThreeJS - Texture multiplied on background

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm building a product configurator, using ThreeJS and a 3d-model to simulate prints on a bottle. Users have to be able to change the color and the print of the bottle. To let users change the print of the bottle, they can upload an image, which is then being used as a texture on a specific mesh of the model.

My problem is, the texture is being multiplied on the model (like a blending effect). The only way to stop this behavior is to use a custom shader. In this case, the texture is no longer multiplied, however, the texture does not react to the lighting of the scene anymore.

I'm new to ThreeJS and 3D modelling. Does anyone have any idea, how to get this texture mapped on my mesh, without multiplying it?

My material setup:

```
var myMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
   map: null,
   transparent: true,
});
```

How I apply the texture:

```
function applyTexture(texture) {
   var myMesh = scene.getObjectByName('Print');
   if (myMesh) {
      myMesh.traverse(function (child) {
         if (child.isMesh) {
         child.material = myMaterial;
            myMaterial.map = texture;
            myMaterial.needsUpdate = true; 
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: By 'background' do you mean the original color of the material, or of something behind the surface? A model's base color is the product of `material.color x material.map x vertex colors`, so if you change `material.color` to white and don't use vertex colors, the texture will be shown as-is. If things behind the model shouldn't affect it, why use `transparent: true`?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Yes, by background I mean the material. Sorry, not that firm with the terminology yet. 

I use transparent: true because the textures can contain transparent areas, which aren't displayed if I don't set transparent: true.